# List of rows of a list

Tags: r, list

I would like to generate a list of all combinations of different elements. I found the expand.grid function which seems to be doing a great job.

```
lCombi<-expand.grid(c(1,2),c(4,5,6),c(7,8))

     Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    4    7
2     2    4    7
3     1    5    7
4     2    5    7
5     1    6    7
6     2    6    7
7     1    4    8
8     2    4    8
9     1    5    8
10    2    5    8
11    1    6    8
12    2    6    8
```

Now, if I understand well, this is a list of 3 elements of 12 rows. But what I would like is a list of 12 elements of 3. I tried to transpose it, convert it into a matrix then back to a list but none worked. So I used my pre-R way of doing things and came up with :

```
iLength=nrow(lCombi)
lResult<-list()
for(i in 1:iLength){
    lResult[[i]]<-lCombi[i,]
}
```

to get my lResult list, which contains what I want. Could you please tell me the more efficient way of doing this please ?

Comment: `transpose` works fine.. As what you have created is not a list but a data frame. `expand.grid` always creates a data frame as output.

Comment: typeof(lCombi) returns [1] "list" for me, so I am a bit confused(although I was surprised as well as expand.grid help says it returns a dataframe)

Comment: `class(lCombi)` gives "data.frame". And `t(lCombi)` gives your desired output.

Comment: `class(lCombi)` gives `"data.frame"`, but data.frames are just 'special' lists anyway.

Comment: OK, thanks, but the transpose visually gives the correct thing, but it does not seem to be a list of 12 elements of 3, if I do lResult[[1]], I got 1 and not [1,4,7] as I would like

Comment: @Djiggy That's because `t()` will coerce to a matrix. `data.table::transpose` will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split` function is great at chopping up a data.frame in to a list of data.frames:

```
lResult <- split(lCombi, 1:nrow(lCombi))
```

If you'd like each list element to be a vector instead, use

```
lapply(lResult, unlist)
```

Comment: Also, to avoid "data.frame" subsetting, `.mapply(c, lCombi, NULL)` concatenates lists in a "parallel" way.